# What other steps to run Groovy by using the SDKMAN install instructions?

Tags: software-installation

Today I went to install Groovy on this Linx Mint 17.2 install.   The SDK (or GVM, [SDKMAN](https://github.com/sdkman)) instructions seemed very clear.

- http://www.groovy-lang.org/install.html

SDKMAN site:

- http://sdkman.io/

Per the install page ...

1. $ `curl -s get.gvmtool.net | bash`
2. $ `source "$HOME/.gvm/bin/gvm-init.sh"`
3. $ `gvm install groovy  #  install the latest stable Groovy`

After installation is complete and you’ve made it your default version, test it with:

4. $ `groovy -version`

The result is completely unexpected.

```
The program 'groovy' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install groovy
```

I executed other reasonable steps, such as ...

- $  `sdk use groovy 2.4.5`

  - It says it worked
- $  `sdk current`

  `No candidates are in use`

Try groovy, same result:

- $ `groovy -version`

  The program 'groovy' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
  sudo apt-get install groovy

When I look, in the `.sdkman` candidates folder, there is indeed a copy of Groovy 2.4.5.  Something in the install script or some step that's not on the instructions is missing.

While I could point an alias at this `groovy`, that rather defeats the purpose of using the `sdk` which would be very useful; provided it works.

I prefer not to manage things like languages and tools manually.  I don't think the `sdk install` works and it may turn out better for me to install from the distribution or package manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was quite simple -- The instructions on Groovy-lang are not current.  Looks like they refer to an older version of the SDKMAN.

Start on the [SDKMAN site](http://sdkman.io/) under **Get Started**:

1. $ `curl -s http://get.sdkman.io | bash`
2. $ `source  ~/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh`
3. $ `sdk install groovy`

Test it out ...

4. $  `groovy -version`

Result:

```
   Groovy Version: 2.4.5 JVM: 1.8.0_66 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Linux
```

One final check, login to a new terminal and try the `groovy -version` again.  It should also work.

The earlier instructions call-down an older version of the install script and probably an older version of the shell initialise script `source`-d in the second step.

For background, you may want to look at the issue resolution on github.

- [sdkman project](https://github.com/sdkman/sdkman-cli)

  - issue: [Groovy is Not running After Install](https://github.com/sdkman/sdkman-cli/issues/396#)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the heads up regarding the faulty page on the Groovy website. It seems like we have two pages, one correct, the other not:

- http://www.groovy-lang.org/install.html
- http://www.groovy-lang.org/download.html

I'll raise a PR to fix this as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

After I did the initial install, I noticed that it did not setup the **current** symlink:

```
.sdkman/candidates/java/:
11.0.15-tem
17.0.3-tem
current -> 11.0.15-tem

.sdkman/candidates/groovy/:
3.0.11
```

So, even if you create a new shell, the login script does not add groovy to the path since you do not have a current version selected.

```
/home/user/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin:/usr/local/bin
```

I then issued:

```
$ sdk use groovy 3.0.11
Setting groovy version 3.0.11 as default.

.sdkman/candidates/groovy/:
3.0.11
current -> 3.0.11
```

which created the symlink. Then, after creating a new session, I had groovy on the path:

```
/home/user/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/current/bin:/home/user/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin:/usr/local/bin:...
```